# Facebook SDK, how to hide "Share" title on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, share

In my Unity3D application for iOS I want to share some info in Facebook. So I have used FB.ShareLink() method in this situation.

But when it shows Share dialog there are two buttons Cancel at the left side and Share at the right side, also there is a title with "Share" text.

How can I delete or hide that "Share" title in the middle of the window?
[image]

Comment: why? Do you think that users might think it is a "share" button?

Comment: yes it is, I think so

Answer (score 0):

```
    public override void ShareLink(
        Uri contentURL,
        string contentTitle,
        string contentDescription,
        Uri photoURL,
        FacebookDelegate<IShareResult> callback)
    {
        MethodArguments args = new MethodArguments();
        args.AddUri("content_url", contentURL);
        args.AddString("content_title", contentTitle);
        args.AddString("content_description", contentDescription);
        args.AddUri("photo_url", photoURL);
        var shareLinkCall = new JavaMethodCall<IShareResult>(this, "ShareLink");
        shareLinkCall.Callback = callback;
        shareLinkCall.Call(args);
    }
```

This is the code that Facebook use for sharing on Android in Facebook Unity SDK. As I see, there is no way to modify share gui from unity plugin, because all of this processes are completed in java classes.

Edit: For editing an external .jar file look at this topic:
[I have an external executable jar file that I wish to edit the java files in it with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055568/i-have-an-external-executable-jar-file-that-i-wish-to-edit-the-java-files-in-it)

Comment: and is there a way to modify that java or obj-c (for iOS) classes?

Comment: you don't need to do this the Facebook Unity SDK offer the same API (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ShareLink)  and it does not solve the issue.

Comment: this code that I shared is from Facebook Unity SDK. And I showed what FB doing in SDK when you call shareLink for android. About solving the issue, I'm sorry but this solves the issue. Saying "there is no way unless facebook give its opensource" is a solution. So people will not waste their time to find for a "non-exist" solution.